# PowerShell GetChildItem exclude file type in base folder but include same file type from sub folder

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I'm trying to find a method of getting `GetChildItem` to include all .xml files found in subfolders, but exclude the .xml files found in the base folder.

My folder structure looks like this:

```
MySubFolder\IncludeThis.xml
MySubFolder\AlsoIncludeThis.xml
AnotherSubFolder\IncludeThis.xml
AnotherSubFolder\AlsoIncludeThis.xml
ExcludeThis.xml
AlsoExcludeThis.xml
```

I've tried using `-Include` and `-Exclude` arguments, without any luck, as these arguments seem to only work on file types and cannot be set to work only on certain folders.

Anyone know how to get `GetChildItem` to filter out the .xml files from the base folder only?

PS) I won't know the names of the sub folders that exist, when using the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the subfolders in a first step and search them for xml Files, e.g.:

```
#Get list of subfolders
$folders = get-childitem -Path [path] -Directory

#Get xml files in subdirectories
$xmlFiles = get-childitem -Path $folders.fullname -Filter '*.xml' -File -recurse
```

Answer (score 0):

While searching the the answer to this question, I came up with a method of achieving what I needed, by combining results from multiple calls to `Get-ChildItem`:

```
#Find the list of all files and folders, including files in sub folders, from a directory:
$All = Get-ChildItem -Recurse

#Find a list of items to exclude from the first list:
$Exclude = Get-ChildItem *.xml

#Remove excluded items from the list of all items:
$Result = $All | Where-Object {$Exclude.FullName -NotContains $_.FullName}

#These terms can be combined into a single difficult-to-read statement:
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object {(Get-ChildItem *.xml).FullName -NotContains $_.FullName}
```